# Installing older gcc, gfortran version on mac big sur

Tags: gcc, homebrew, gfortran

I am trying to install (with pip install) on a mac BigSur a python package that needs `gfortran`.
The package was last updated in 2020.

I initially did

```
brew install gcc
```

and that brought in gfortran, but my pip install failed with some fortran errors.
My theory is that I need to revert to an older (circa 2020) version of `gfortran`.

I did

```
brew install gcc@8
```

but when I run

```
gfortran --version
```

it doesnt find `gfortran`.

I am a beginner with brew. Not sure what am I missing in these install games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are halfway there. Run these now

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/gfortran-8 /usr/local/bin/gfortran
ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc-8 /usr/local/bin/gcc
```

The full process is explained here [Updating and installing GNU/gfortran compiler on MacOS](https://wiki.usask.ca/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1935648493)